# How to set variables in nextex ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to set some variable in ssh session which is nested and read them too.

```
ssh host1 << EOF 
    ssh host2 << EOF1 
       myvar="Hello"

    EOF1
    echo=\$myvar
EOF
```

Please tell what is wrong in bash script.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to get some value form host2 to host1.

Comment: `ssh host1 -- 'var=$(ssh host2 -- '\''echo $somevar'\'')';echo "$var"` should work. If you do is on larger scale or with more complex scripts, think about using `ansible` for that